# AWS S3 downloaded pdf writestream becomes zero bytes on download

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am downloading a pdf from an aws s3 bucket in a node.js express server, and then writing that pdf to file in an uploads folder:

```
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var params = {
    Bucket: 'aliro-pdf-assets',
    Key: req.body.query
};
var out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/uploads/' + req.body.query);
s3.getObject(params).
  on('httpData', function(chunk) { out.write(chunk); }).
  on('httpDone', function() {
    out.end();
    res.send('http done');
  }).send();
```

After that (in the callback in the front-end ajax call to download this pdf), I try and render it on the front end like so:

```
<object data="/uploads/' + pdata.pdf + '" width="98%" height="1300" type="application/pdf">
  <p>You don\'nt have a PDF plugin for this browser. Click Download PDF up in the top left to view the PDF anyway!</p>\
</object>
```

and also like this:

```
<a id="pdfDown" href="/uploads/' + pdata.pdf + '" class= "btn btn-danger btn-sm downloadPDF"><img src="images/pdfIcon.png">Download PDF</a>\
```

(`pdata.pdf` is the name of the pdf, the same as `req.body.query` in the server)

Problem is, both of these renderings don't work. PDF.JS gives me this error:

```
Error: stream must have data pdf.worker.js:237:5
assert@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:254:5
init@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2343:5
PDFDocument@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:2334:7
NetworkPdfManager@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1996:24
getPdfManager@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:33775:24
wphSetupDoc@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:33979:7
messageHandlerComObjOnMessage@resource://pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js:1247:9
 pdf.worker.js:238:1
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown" pdf.worker.js:224:5
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown" pdf.js:224:5
An error occurred while loading the PDF.
PDF.js v1.1.551 (build: 2a5616c)
Message: stream must have data
```

What's wrong? I know I am accessing the right files in s3, but the pdfs I actually receive on the front-end are zero bytes!